# Adding AnyObject to NSMutableArray in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nspredicate

I just trying to do Tableview Search. I'm using `NSPredicate` for searching.

Every tutorial people giving this code line:

```
let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF contains[c] %@", searchText)
self.nameArray = self.nameArray.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(resultPredicate)
```

But in second line Xcode saying: `Cannot assign a value of type '[AnyObject]' to a value of type 'NSMutableArray'`

I tried to convert but this time xcode founding nil value. My both array is `NSMutableArray`. Any Advice?

**EDIT**

My cell codes:

```
let cell:ItemsTVCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as! ItemsTVCell

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView {
        cell.itemNameLabel.text = filteredArray[indexPath.row] as? String
    } else {
        cell.itemNameLabel.text = nameArray[indexPath.row] as? String
    }

    return cell
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`filteredArrayUsingPredicate` returns [AnyObject], and it looks like your property is of type NSMutableArray. You have a few options, in order of preference:

- Change your property to be a Swift array (e.g. `var nameArray: [String]`) instead of NSMutableArray. Instead of using `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`, just use the array's filter method:

  `self.nameArray = self.nameArray.filter({contains($0.lowercaseString, searchText.lowercaseString})`
- If you must continue to keep your property as a NSMutableArray, you can create an instance of NSArray with the contents of the filtered array:

  `NSMutableArray(array: self.nameArray.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(resultPredicate))`

Comment: I already tried your second idea. But xcode saying `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) ` I added my cell codes to my question.

Comment: Just a note: there's no such thing as a member variable in Swift. `nameArray` is a property, which Swift exposes through accessor methods. The underlying storage for Swift properties is opaque.

Comment: What line throws the optional value error, the array constructor?

Comment: @rudd at this line: `let cell:ItemsTVCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as! ItemsTVCell`

Comment: @jlehr: Good catch, bouncing around languages today, edited.

Comment: @SalihÇiftçi: Looks like an unrelated bug to your array issue,  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is returning nil (which it can) and you aren't handling it. Try this one-liner to get a non-optional cell: ```var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? ItemsTVCell ?? ItemsTVCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: identifier)```. Best to avoid !s in future Swift code.